# Odd Mod_Rewrite Behaviour

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've had a look at a few mod_rewrite questions here but nothing they have suggested has worked to date.

I have the below rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/$ ?action=$1 [L]

## General Pages
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy/$ ?action=privacy-policy [L]
RewriteRule ^terms-conditions/$ ?action=terms-conditions [L]
RewriteRule ^about/$ ?action=about [L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us/$ ?action=contact-us [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ ?action=sitemap [L]

## Blog Pages
RewriteRule ^blog/$ ?action=blog [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ ?action=blog&category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ ?action=blog&category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

The first `blog` rule works fine and the third `blog` rule works fine.

The second `blog` rule isn't working correctly, lets say I have the below URL:

```
/blog/general/
```

The second `blog` rule is returning `blog/general` as the value for `category`which is incorrect, it should only be returning `general` as the value for `category`.

This issue only occurs on my production environment, it doesn't happen on my local dev environment.

I'm really stumped on this one, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Do you have other rules as well?

Comment: @anubhava, no other rules relating to blogs, there are about another 10/15 rules for other areas of the website. The issue doesn't occur on my local dev environment, only on my production environment, very odd.

Comment: @anubhava blog isn't a directory no, it's a virtual path, there is only on htaccess file on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reordering your rules and merge `SSL` with `www` rule to avoid multiple redirects (bad for SEO and client experience):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

## General Pages
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy/$ ?action=privacy-policy [L]
RewriteRule ^terms-conditions/$ ?action=terms-conditions [L]
RewriteRule ^about/$ ?action=about [L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us/$ ?action=contact-us [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ ?action=sitemap [L]

## Blog Pages
RewriteRule ^blog/$ ?action=blog [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ ?action=blog&category=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ ?action=blog&category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/$ ?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Working perfectly now, I suppose it was the general catch all rewrite for the action parameter causing the issue.

Comment: That generic rules should come at the end.